# Can't seem to make jQuery onClick fadeOut work on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is killing me.  I have spent the better part of two days trying to make this work.

Ultimately, what I am trying to achieve is have a list of 3 items, "Light", "Regular", and "Deep" trigger the fade in of a specific div matched to each item on the list.  I am using z-index to layer the divs above a background div.

So when I click on "Light", an image fades in above the background div, and if "Regular" or "Deep" are visible at the time of the click, they fade out (only 1 would be visible at a time anyway).

Basically, the jQuery is set up like this:

```
$('#main_right_line_one').click(function(){
    $('#main_regular_layover, #main_deep_layover').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#main_light_layover').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#main_right_line_two').click(function(){    
    $('#main_light_layover, #main_deep_layover').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#main_regular_layover').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});

$('#main_right_line_three').click(function(){
    $('#main_light_layover, #main_regular_layover').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        $('#main_deep_layover').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

I have my html set up like this:

```
<div id="main_container">
          <div id="main_top_left">
          </div>
          <div id="main_top_right">
                <a id="main_right_line_one" href="#">Light</a><br />
                <a id="main_right_line_two" href="#">Regular</a><br />
                <a id="main_right_line_three" href="#">Deep</a>
          </div>
          <div id="main_bottom">
          </div>
          <div id="main_light_layover">
                <img class="light_layover" src="/images/light_layover.png" />
          </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
#main_light_layover
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:8;
    overflow:visible;
}

.light_layover
{

    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:-60px;
    z-index:8;
}
```

My jQuery isn't that great, but this simply isn't working.  I'm wondering if it's having problems since the target for the click is within a second div?

I started playing around with it more to see if I could get something more simple to work, like loading the image normally and using jQuery to fade it out on click, but I can't even get that to work on my specific page, yet I can get a barebones version to work on jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/197/

It seems like I simply can't get the target for fading to work at all on my specific page.  Can anyone offer some insight?

EDIT - Here is a jsFiddle working the way I want the page to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/3XwZv/507/

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery selector is correct?  For example, you reference #light_layover, but in your code light_layover is a class not an id (e.g .light_layover)?

Comment: I pasted an old chunk of JS.  I updated the OP to reflect the actual code being used.  Also, a link to the actual page below.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the e in your click function

```
$('#main_right_line_one').click(function(){
$('#regular_layover, #deep_layover').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#main_light_layover').show('slow');
});
});

$('#main_right_line_two').click(function(){    
$('#light_layover, #deep_layover').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#regular_layover').fadeIn('slow');
});
});

 $('#main_right_line_three').click(function(){
$('#light_layover, #regular_layover').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $('#deep_layover').fadeIn('slow');
});
 });
```

Comment: That should make no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your post, you selectors are off.

`#` is the prefix used for ids, `.` is the prefix used for classes

Thus you want as selector `$('.light_layover')`, not `$('#light_layover')`.

Also, if your div is hidden, your image may not be shown. So maybe you meant to be using `$('#main_light_layover')` rather than using just 'light_layover'?

EDIT: Looking at your code... You need to make sure that the elements from your selector are already loaded in the DOM before running `$(selector)`. You can do this via `$(document).ready(initialize)` where `initialize` is the function that sets up the click handlers.

See [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I actually pasted an old chunk of code.  In the script, I am using all ids for the classes.  Here is a link to the actual page:

http://padjumpers.com

Comment: After looking at your js/main.js file, I think you are executing the `$(selector).click` methods to early. Try sticking them into a `function init () {...}` function and running init on load with `$.ready(init)` (outside of the init function of course).

Comment: So you think my scripts are running too soon?  I'm gonna throw this together and give it a shot.  I'm just trying to understand what the difference would be.

Comment: Load your page and look at the developer console.  You'll see "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" (Chrome).  This occurs in your main.js as Shadow Creeper pointed out.  I didn't notice a <script src=...> reference to jQuery either.

Comment: If the script runs, doing `jQuery('#myId')` before the `#myId` object is loaded into the DOM, the `jQuery` command will return an empty list as the object wasn't there yet. And also, as @veritasetratio pointed out, you forgot to include _jquery.js_ in your page.